# additive interaction，why SI was null

Tags: interaction

I have seen the results of additive interaction analysis in a paper I don't understand what is the meaning of the result expression of NA here and why it is NA, can you explain it to me please.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Description of the original paper： No interaction was found between TyG
index classes and subgroup variables (Table 4). The SI of
education level or marital status in addictive interaction
analysis was null because of meaningless statistical value.
Original link：https://cardiab.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12933-023-01870-z
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLYGr.png

Comment: It would be very useful to include (a reference to) the [original paper](https://doi.org/10.1186%2Fs12933-023-01870-z).